# How to send text written in p:editor primefaces to java bean without submit?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I work with primefaces 5.3 and java 8. I've a p:editor and when I write some text into I want that it's directly send to my bean but I've two problems :

- when I use "onchange" in the p:editor it slow down other process that I do in my page after typing on the editor... So I must find an other away to process my editor's text or stop the process which seems to continue on the editor after text writting.
- I've try to use "valueChangeListener" instead of onchange in the p:editor but it works only when submitted... and ajax doesn't work on p:editor...

Have you an idea?

Here with onchange :

```
<p:remoteCommand name="ajoutText" process="@parent" update="@none" />
<p:editor value="#{bean.text}"
                            id="editorId"
                             onchange="ajoutTxt()"                      
                            widgetVar="editorId"
                            controls="bold italic underline | color highlight removeformat | bullets numbering | alignleft center alignright justify | cut copy"
                            process="@this"/>
```

Here with valueChangeListener :

```
<p:editor value="#{beanFormDocument.monDocument.travAreal}"
                            id="travauxAreal"
                            valueChangeListener="#{beanFormDocument.valeurTravArealChange}"                     
                            widgetVar="travauxAreal"
                            controls="bold italic underline | color highlight removeformat | bullets numbering | alignleft center alignright justify | cut copy"
                            process="@this">
                            <f:ajax/>
                        </p:editor>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please define what "when I write some text" means? When and how often should that event be triggered?

Comment: When I write something in the editor, when I click out of it (ideally), I want that my text is send to the bean to be processed. Do you see what I want?

Comment: Tried adding `p:ajax event="blur"`?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to this problem

```
    <p:editor id="editor" widgetVar="editorWidget" style="width:100%;" disabled="#{paramMBean.modoConsultarVisualizacao}" value="#{paramMBean.loteLiquidacao.observacao}"
        controls="bold italic underline strikethrough color size subscript superscript bullets undo redo cut copy paste pastetext" onchange="rc()">
    </p:editor>     
    <p:remoteCommand name="salvarObservacao" process="@parent" update="@none" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function rc()
        {
            salvarObservacao();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).